# How to avoid lftp Certificate verification error?

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, ftp, verification

I'm trying to get my [Pelican blog](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/) working. It uses lftp to transfer the actual blog to ones server, but I always get an error:

```
mirror: Fatal error: Certificate verification: subjectAltName does not match ‘blogname.com’
```

I think lftp is checking the SSL and the quick setup of Pelican just forgot to include that I don't have SSL on my FTP.

---

This is the code in Pelican's Makefile:

```
ftp_upload: $(OUTPUTDIR)/index.html
lftp ftp://$(FTP_USER)@$(FTP_HOST) -e "mirror -R $(OUTPUTDIR) $(FTP_TARGET_DIR) ; quit"
```

which renders in terminal as:

```
    lftp ftp://username@blogname.com -e "mirror -R /Volumes/HD/Users/me/Test/output /myblog_directory ; quit"
```

---

What I managed so far is, denying the SSL check by changing the Makefile to:

```
lftp ftp://$(FTP_USER)@$(FTP_HOST) -e "set ftp:ssl-allow no" "mirror -R $(OUTPUTDIR) $(FTP_TARGET_DIR) ; quit"
```

Due to my incorrect implementation I get logged in correctly (`lftp username@myblog.com:~>`) but the one line feature doesn't work anymore and I have to enter the mirror command by hand:

```
mirror -R /Volumes/HD/Users/me/Test/output/ /myblog_directory
```

This works without an error and timeout. **The question is how to do this with a one liner.**

---

In addition I tried:

- `set ssl:verify-certificate/ftp.myblog.com no`
- [This trick](http://anils-tips.blogspot.de/2011/05/lftp-fatal-error-certificate.html) to disable certificate verification in lftp:

  $ cat ~/.lftp/rc 
  set ssl:verify-certificate no

However, it seems there is no "rc" folder in my lftp directory - so this prompt has no chance to work.

Comment: `~/.lftprc`  is a file

Comment: Check this out https://serverok.in/download-all-files-from-ftp-server-using-lftp it might be very helpful

Answer (score 62, accepted):

From the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/lftp):

> -c commands
>   Execute the given commands and exit. Commands can be separated with a semicolon (`;`), AND (`&&`) or OR (`||`). Remember to quote the commands argument properly in the shell.  This option must be used alone without other arguments.

So you want to specify the commands as a single argument, separated by semicolons:

```
lftp ftp://$(FTP_USER)@$(FTP_HOST) -e "set ftp:ssl-allow no; mirror -R $(OUTPUTDIR) $(FTP_TARGET_DIR) ; quit"
```

You can actually omit the `quit` command and use `-c` instead of `-e`.

Comment: That's great. Thanks a ton. I had hoped that someone who's more experienced than me would spot my failure instantly ( - I also tried your -c suggestion leaving out the quit, but this didn't work for me. I'm happy anyway).

Answer (score 56):

I had a similar issue, though my lftp does have ssl support compiled in (Fedora RPM).  `ssl:verify-certificate false` did the trick for me.

Comment: Based on this, putting `set ssl:verify-certificate false` in my `~/.lftprc` solved the problem for me.

Comment: …though that defeats the point of using SSL your lftp now happily accepts whatever certificate it gets presented, making you vulnerable to M2M attacks.

Comment: If certificates are not validated properly, a likely cause is that lftp does not find the CA certificates of your system. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44095714/651937) for a fix.

Answer (score 40):

### no certificate check

`echo "set ssl:verify-certificate no" >> ~/.lftp/rc`

will solve the problem if you **dont want** the certificate to be checked

### The secure solution with certificate is

What worked for me step by step with lftp:

1. **get certificate** of host with `openssl s_client -connect <ftp_hostname>:21 -starttls ftp`, at the begining of result I got something like `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   MIIEQzCCAyu.....XjMO
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----`
2. **copy** that `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   MIIEQzCCAyu.....XjMO
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----` **into** `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`
3. Into **lftp configuration** reference this certificate file adding to `/etc/lftp.conf` for systemwide `set ssl:ca-file "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"`
4. and then do your sync or whatever with `lftp`, on my case it is `lftp -u "${FTP_USER},${FTP_PWD}" ${FTP_HOST} -e "set net:timeout 10;mirror ${EXCLUDES} -R ${LOCAL_SOURCE_PATH} ${REMOTE_DEST_PATH} ; quit"`

Comment: This still disables verification of SSL certificates and this makes man-in-the-middle attacks possible. For a better fix, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44095714/651937).

Comment: better just execute `set ssl:verify-certificate no` in lftp shell to disable temporary for current session than disabling always. Still +1 for the solution.

Comment: @ingomueller.net I present the 2 alternatives, the first yes, the other not

Comment: Please not that if your certificate is expired adding it to the ca-certificates has no effect. We we're using a self-signed cert and it took me a moment to realize that the reason we couldn't connect was because of the expiration.

Comment: It's `echo "set ssl:verify-certificate no" >> ~/.lftprc`.

Comment: To handle a self-signed cert without admin rights, you could also paste the certificate into a user-writable text file, and put `set ssl:ca-file "/path/to/my-ca-file.txt"` into ~/.lftprc file.  You may also need `set ssl:check-hostname no` if the hostname on the certificate doesn't match.

Answer (score 9):

`ssl:verfy-certificate false` didn't work for me, I was getting a timeout error when "making data connection".

I followed [these](http://networklessons.com/linux/lftp-stuck-making-data-connection/) instruction by adding `set ftp:ssl-allow false` to my `~/.lftprc` file.

Comment: Did you spell it right when you ran the command? ssl:verify-certificate false

Answer (score 8):

I was also facing similar sort of ssl certificate verification error. Setting verify-certificate to 'no' worked for me.

Example:

lftp -c 'set ftps:initial-prot ""; set ftp:ssl-force true; set ftp:ssl-protect-data true; **set ssl:verify-certificate no;** open -u Usename,Password 208.82.204.46; put uploadfilename;'

Comment: This should be the "correct" answer, IMO, as it is the only one that doesn't involve modifying the configuration file with a setting that could do more harm than good and which should be used with care in very specific situations. Thanks for taking the time sharing this, Pritam.

Answer (score 5):

> In addition I tried:
>
> - set ssl:verify-certificate/ftp.myblog.com no
> - [This](http://anils-tips.blogspot.de/2011/05/lftp-fatal-error-certificate.html) trick to disable    certificate verification in lftp:
>
> $ cat ~/.lftp/rc set ssl:verify-certificate no

Try using `set ftp:ssl-allow no`; it worked like a charm for me.

Comment: This is the most appropriate choice. The global setting is a bad choice as it is reasonable to use certificate verification when possible and by setting the global option it will never try to verify the certificate. You can use a script file `lftp -f <script>` and place this command before the open command.

Comment: `set ssl:verify-certificate no` is better I think because the transaction remains secured. `set ftp:ssl-allow no` will communicate plaintext

Answer (score 3):

I have read man pages and found solution.
Create file

```
~/.lftp/rc
```

and add there next line:

```
set ssl:check-hostname false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Need the lftp command: `set ftp:ssl-allow no;`

You could execute the command just after selecting:

```
lftp www.yourdomain.com -u username,password -e "set ftp:ssl-allow no;"
```

or save the command into `~/.lftprc`.

Comment: this only definitive disable TLS negotiation, you will connect with raw mode without any encryption. Of course this will be done, if user on the host allows unencrypted connection.

Answer (score 1):

Solved using this:

```
lftp ftp://$(FTP_USER)@$(FTP_HOST) -e "set ssl:verify-certificate no; mirror -R $(OUTPUTDIR) $(FTP_TARGET_DIR) ; quit"
```

example:

```
lftp ftp://username@blogname.com -e "set ssl:verify-certificate no; mirror -R /Volumes/HD/Users/me/Test/output /myblog_directory ; quit"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lftp -u username,password host -e "set ftp:ssl-allow no"
```

fixed the issue for me